# how to add azure alerts when we get server error

Tags: azure, amazon-cloudwatch, azure-alerts

1. I need to set an azure alert to my azure function http triggered. When I have an internal server error (500) then I need to send an alert email to a group of emails.
2. How to create a azure dash board to get the number of hits to an API.

need a better solution for alert email template and alerts setting.

Answer (score 1):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create azure alerts when the function gets HTTP 500 server error:**

1. **Azure alert when azure function http triggered**.

I have created a function app, like below.

**Azure portal > Function App >Create**

[image]

Create a function with visual studio and upload the same to the function app.

Sample code to create an exception.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    throw new Exception("An error has occurred.");
}
```

Once publish the code to Azure Function app, check the Function Status. Like below.

**Azure Portal > Function App > Select your Function app >Functions.**

[image]

Run the function and check the result, like below.

**Open Functions >Code + Test > Test/Run**

> Note: Body section add above vs code to get 500 server error.

[image]

**Output**

[image]

To generate the alert for HTTP 500 error.

**Functions > Monitor > Run query in Application Insights**

Query to check 500 internal error.

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    id,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'httpdtriggeredfunc01' and operation_Name =~ 'Function1'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

[image]

Click on a new alert rule to generate the alert for the same error.

**Create an action group with your DL email id**.

[image]

When the function triggered **HTTP 500 internal server** error, you will get an alert to your mail id.

[image]

**Successfully received an email.**

[image]

**2.  How to create an azure dashboard to get the number of hits to an API.**

To create a dashboard for the function app.

**Open your function app > Application Insights > View Application Insights data.**

[image]

Once open the application Insights data and select the application dashboard option, it will create a dashboard for your function app automatically.

[image]